# Truepush Webpush Notification Integration with Laravel

Tags: push-notification, notifications, laravel-8, integration

I want to use truepush webpush notification service with my application: According to there API documentation i have successful created campaign but notification not sent to all subscriber.
Below is my code:

````
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.truepush.com/api/v1/createCampaign',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
  "userInteraction":true,
    "title": "Government Jobs in Pakistan",
    "message":  "Like here for Latest Jobs in Pakistan",
    "link":  "https://jobshut.pk",
    "image":  "https://jobshut.pk/admin_asset/images/1667923790.png",
    "icon": "https://jobshut.pk/admin_asset/images/1667923790.png",
    "buttons": [
        {
            "text": "FaceBook",
            "link": "https://www.facebook.com/jobshut.pk/"
        },
        {
            "text": "Twitter",
            "link": "https://twitter.com/JobshutP?lang=en"
        }
    ]
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: xxxxxxxxx',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=7ec0fa47-4c57-50b8-82c6-dd4d780d86c4'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spM88.png)

I need solution, When i post the notification should send to all subscribers.
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your response dear, I want to send notification to all subscriber through given api call through truespush. But it creates only campaign not send the notification. is there any problem with it?